# Caching: APC vs APCu vs OPcache

Tags: cache, apc

I'm a bit confused and I'd like to know the difference between the [APC](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php), [APCu](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php), and [OPcache](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php).

I'm using:

- WHM VPS Apache 2.4
- PHP 5.5
- Fastcgi
- Processor 6 vCores
- RAM
- 8 Gio

Comment: APC development has stopped as far as I know, do you have a specific question or problem?

Answer (score 26):

The mix up is usually because these extensions are about two unrelated technologies: opcode caching and key-value data store. For WordPress you prefereably want both. Opcode caching is really the "normal" way to run PHP (and lack of it is essentially crippled shared hosting way). Data store can *(and should) be used by WordPress object cache plugins for better persistent caching.

So out of those you named:

- APC is opcode cache *and* data store
- APCu is *only* data store
- OPcache is *only* opcode cache

Since APC is older, at the moment you likely want OPcache as well as some data store, not necessarily APCu (although it is perfectly fine choice).

Comment: Thanks for u Answer, So if i understanded well you recomend using OPcache & APCu. that s good just 1 last question this wont take so mush memory or cpu from my server if i use both ?
Thanks

Comment: @Dolomats yes, that would be viable option, but there would be other alternatives as well (just for context).

Comment: Waw 26s and i got answer :d. so just by curiosity what s can be the other alternatives you suggest !

Comment: @Dolomats Memcache and Redis are typical alternatives for data store. There are several alternate solutions for opcode caching as well, but not as popular relatively.

Comment: Memcache is popular was thinking about so memcache do same work as APC then i can use Memcache with OPcode ? or just Memcache instead of both ?

Comment: @Dolomats Memcache is a data store, so you could use it with OPcache (opcode) in place of APCu (data store).